# Select statement works fine, but select into fails with a date conversion error

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, type-conversion

I've got a SQL statement that turn a few date strings into dates. This works fine when just selecting the data. However, when I try to use it in a Union or when I try to insert it into a temp table I get a conversion error.

This is the SQL

```
  SELECT  'EXISTING' source,
    ep.Tenant,
    ep.[server],
    ep.[Database],
    ep.[Model],
    ep.[Table],
    ep.[name],
    ep.irisSplitColumnValues,
    convert(date,nullif(left(replace(ep.irisFrom,'/','-'),10),'1900-01-01'),105) irisFrom,
    convert(date,nullif(left(replace(ep.irisTo,'/','-'),10),'1900-01-01'),105) irisTo,
    [Definition],
    iif(left(ep.[name],5) = 'AUTO_',null,tp.[Object]) as [Object],
    ep.sourceType,
    cast(nullif(ep.modifiedTime,'1/1/1900 12:00:00 AM') as datetime) modifiedTime,
    cast(nullif(ep.refreshedTime,'1/1/1900 12:00:00 AM') as datetime) refreshedTime,
    iif(left(ep.[name],5) = 'AUTO_',1,0) as [SystemManaged],
    CASE WHEN left(ep.[name],5) = 'AUTO_' and tp.PartitionName IS NOT NULL  THEN 'Merge'
         WHEN ts.managedBy = 'System' THEN 'Delete'
         ELSE 'UserManaged'
    END  as Action,
    tp.PartitionName as Target
    --into #tmp2
from LoadManagement.PbiExistingPartitions ep
left join Loadmanagement.fxPbiCalculatePartitions() cp on ep.Tenant = cp.Tenant 
                                                 and ep.[server] = cp.Workspace
                                                 and ep.[Database] = cp. [Database]
                                                 and ep.Model = cp.Model
                                                 and ep.[Table] = cp.[Table]
                                                 and ep.[Definition] = cp.[DefinitionSQL] 
left join Loadmanagement.fxPbiCalculatePartitions() tp on ep.Tenant = cp.Tenant 
                                                 and ep.[server] = cp.Workspace
                                                 and ep.[Database] = cp. [Database]
                                                 and ep.Model = cp.Model
                                                 and ep.[Table] = cp.[Table]
                                                 and ep.[Definition] <> cp.[DefinitionSQL] 
                                                 and ep.irisSplitColumnValues = cp.SplitColumnValues
                                                 and  convert(date,nullif(left(replace(ep.irisFrom,'/','-'),10),'1900-01-01'),105) <= cp.fromDate
                                                 and  convert(date,nullif(left(replace(ep.irisTo,'/','-'),10),'1900-01-01'),105) >= cp.toDate
left join [LoadManagement].[PbiTableSettings]       ts on ep.Tenant     = ts.Tenant 
                                                 and ep.[server]        = ts.Workspace
                                                 and ep.[Database]      = ts. [Database]
                                                 and ep.Model           = ts.Model
                                                 and ep.[Table]         = ts.[Table]
Where cp.PartitionName IS NULL AND ep.sourceType in ('Query','M')
```

Ths issue seems to be with the second date conversion in the join on the TP table function.

If I leave that one out, it works fine.

This is the a sample of the result of this query ( same value have been replaced )

[image]

Comment: Take the time to provide us with a [mre], so that we can replicate the issue.

Comment: A clause like `convert(date,nullif(left(replace(ep.irisFrom,'/','-'),10),'1900-01-01'),105)` implies you aren't storing your date (and time) data as a date (and time) data type; that is the *real* problem here. Fix your design, fix your problem.

Comment: Of course, just minutes after posting I finally get the answer myself. I don't fully understand why, but when using the convert in a Union of Insert it doesn't like NULL values. So I handled the NULL's before conversion and this seems to work fine.

convert(date,isnull(nullif(left(replace(ep.irisFrom,'/','-'),10),'1900-01-01'),'01-01-1900'),105) irisFrom,

Answer (score -1):

When using the convert in a Union or Insert it doesn't like NULL values. So I handled the NULL's before conversion and this seems to work fine. convert(date,isnull(nullif(left(replace(ep.irisFrom,'/','-'),10),'1900

Comment: *"When using the convert in a Union or Insert it doesn't like NULL values"* This certainly sounds like the wrong answer. `INSERT` and `UNION` have no issues with `NULL` values.